# Finding My Favourite Questions

Tags: support, bookmarks

I would like to be able to locate the questions that I have marked as FAVOURITE. How can I do that?  I have tried to find the answer in the FAQ's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your user profile, under the activity tab, you'll find [a tab](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites) listing all your favorites.